# Stuck in Abbreviation implementation to ruby string

Tags: ruby, string

I want to convert all the words(alphabetic) in the string to their abbreviations like i18n does.  In other words I want to change `"extraordinary"` into "e11y" because there are 11 characters between the first and the last letter in `"extraordinary"`. It  works with a single word in  the string. But how can I do the same for a multi-word string? And of course if a word is `<= 4` there is  no point to make an abbreviation from it.

```
class Abbreviator

  def self.abbreviate(x)
    x.gsub(/\w+/, "#{x[0]}#{(x.length-2)}#{x[-1]}")
  end

end

Test.assert_equals( Abbreviator.abbreviate("banana"), "b4a", Abbreviator.abbreviate("banana") )
Test.assert_equals( Abbreviator.abbreviate("double-barrel"), "d4e-b4l", Abbreviator.abbreviate("double-barrel") )
Test.assert_equals( Abbreviator.abbreviate("You, and I, should speak."), "You, and I, s4d s3k.", Abbreviator.abbreviate("You, and I, should speak.") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def short_form(str)
  str.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]{4,}/) { |s| "%s%d%s" % [s[0], s.size-2, s[-1]] }
end
```

The regex reads, "match four or more alphabetic characters".

```
short_form "abc"          # => "abc" 
short_form "a-b-c"        #=> "a-b-c" 
short_form "cats"         #=> "c2s" 
short_form "two-ponies-c" #=> "two-p4s-c" 
short_form "Humpty-Dumpty, who sat on a wall, fell over"
  #=> "H4y-D4y, who sat on a w2l, f2l o2r"
```

Comment: Thanks to @KirillZhuravlov for flagging a mistake I made.

Comment: I initially thought the conversion only applied to words or hyphenated words. I've modified my answer to deal with strings.

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is that your second parameter is a substitution string operating on `x` (the original entire string) as a whole.

Instead of using the form of `gsub` where the second parameter is a substitution string, use the form of `gsub` where the second parameter is a *block* (listed, for example, third on [this page](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub)). Now you are receiving *each substring* into your block and can operate on *that* substring individually.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend something along the lines of this:

```
class Abbreviator
  def self.abbreviate(x)
    x.gsub(/\w+/) do |word|
      # Skip the word unless it's long enough
      next word unless word.length > 4
      # Do the same I18n conversion you do before
      "#{word[0]}#{(word.length-2)}#{word[-1]}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer isn't bad, but it can be made a lot simpler by not matching words that are too short in the first place:

```
def abbreviate(str)
  str.gsub(/([[:alpha:]])([[:alpha:]]{3,})([[:alpha:]])/i) { "#{$1}#{$2.size}#{$3}" }
end

abbreviate("You, and I, should speak.")
# => "You, and I, s4d s3k."
```

Alternatively, we can use lookbehind and lookahead, which makes the Regexp more complex but the substitution simpler:

```
def abbreviate(str)
  str.gsub(/(?<=[[:alpha:]])[[:alpha:]]{3,}(?=[[:alpha:]])/i, &:size)
end
```

Comment: I believe that this answer is more complete

Comment: The question is not clear on which characters can be in the string that is converted. They might be alphabetic characters, alphanumeric characters, or all characters, but I doubt that they would be  "word characters" (`\w`), considering that `"_______"str.gsub(/(\w)(\w{3,})(\w)/) { "#{$1}#{$2.size}#{$3}" } #=> "_5_"`. If `"_5_"` is OK, then why not `"-5-"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland OP used `\w` in their own code, so I made a deductive leap.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are right, my question was not fully clean. I will change it.